# Linear gradient combined with image background not displaying

Tags: html, css

I have a section which I have added a linear gradient as background plus image , unfortunately only linear gradient is displaying no image is displayed .

I have used all solution in stackoverflow but nothing worked.

Here is my code:

```css
.newslater {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: linear-gradient( 51deg, rgb(203, 0, 53) 0%, rgb(224, 105, 0) 100%), url("https://thumb.ibb.co/ekYLtp/Content_bottom.png") no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 489px;
}
```

```html
<section class="newslater">

</section>
```

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n7dofak9/1/

I am strugling to solve this problem :( , what am I doing wrong in my code? please help

Comment: the gradient is covering the image

Comment: You're stacking the images the wrong way; the first (counter-intuitively) covers the second: for example: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/n7dofak9/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this is simple, your mistake is that you're using RGB(), what you should be using is RGBA() which allows you to add transparency to your gradient, when you use RGB() for your gradient, you get a **solid** gradient, therefore the gradient will cover the image you're trying to input!

*Note: RGBA(x,x,x,y) the y value (representing transparency) can only take in values from 0-1 in decimal points, with 1 being solid and 0 being entirely transparent, if you want the gradient to be lighter, go lower, if you want the gradient to be darker, go higher.

Let me know if you have any issues!

Do upvote me!

Corrected code:

```
.newslater {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
background: linear-gradient( 51deg, rgb(203,0,53, 0.5) 0%, rgb(224,105,0, 0.5) 
100%), url("https://thumb.ibb.co/ekYLtp/Content_bottom.png");
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
height: 489px;
}
```

Comment: Am testing if it works I will accept your answer, thanks

Comment: Thanks Kenal , your solution works perfect, so I would like my background to look like this https://ibb.co/jKKSpU , what do I need to change to get the expected result?

Comment: Hey! all you need to do is to simply change the link within the url("...") parameter, so it'll look something like

background: linear-gradient( 51deg, rgb(203,0,53, 0.5) 0%, rgb(224,105,0, 0.5) 
100%), url("ibb.co/jKKSpU");

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/n7dofak9/3/

```
.newslater {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
background-image: 
linear-gradient(217deg, rgba(255,0,0,.8), rgba(255,0,0,0) 70.71%), url('https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/colorful-circles-walpaper-3d-seamless-260nw-306246791.jpg');
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
height: 489px;
```

}

You can look at this address.
Would you try that?

Comment: please don't spam with many answers, try to edit your old one or delete it